# Determine page number when using Solr cursorMark

Tags: solr

I am building an application with Solr that should give users the first *N* results of a search, and using `cursorMark` to paginate through *R* rows at a time.

The problem is that with the client+server relationship, the client knows the page number and the `cursorMark`, but the server is only told the `cursorMark`. It's also not safe to trust a page number from the client.

Is there any way I'd be able to determine the offset from a given `cursorMark` server-side without also storing a list of `page number` + `cursorMark` combinations for every search?

For example, I'd like to be able to reject a request after using a `cursorMark` that would yield results `> 10000` for a given search.

Comment: The whole thing about cursormarks is to avoid having to consider page numbers and offsets into the result set to avoid having the pagination scale badly when running distributed. In general cursorMark makes the most sense when you're doing deep pagination (.. so when you're actually at page 10k). When you're not, and especially if you're not using cloud mode, regular pagination could work fine. When the result can be resolved on a single node, the pagination request can be answered (even for deep offsets) by directly looking up the sorted set locally.

Comment: Then the question really becomes: what value does a "page number" provide, valid or not? Do you need to know the abstract value of a page number? Is there more sensible ways of navigating through a result set that can be provided? There's also the option of "signing" a request, where you generate a hash server side based on `secret + page number + cursorMark`, and you give the client both the page number, the cursor mark and the hash, and you can the revalidate the hash server side - if you really need to give the client information you can verify later (look at hmacs).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. but some apis like Stripe let you specify `before=cursor` and `after=cursor`. I was hoping for something like this?

Comment: Since Stripe implements it using the object id, you I guess you can replicate it by using your own unique id field and doing a range search? i.e. `fq=unique_field:[after_cursor_value TO before_cursor_value]`. Stripe will not give you a page number either, so it would be the same-ish. The cursorMark is an abstraction that moves some of this logic from your controller to Solr.